# How would you calculate a derivative of $ f(x)= \frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{2-x}$ by the limit definition?

Tags: limits, derivatives

**I have a function defined as follows:**
$$
f(x)= \frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{2-x}
$$

*I tried to calculate the derivative using the limit definition using four methods, but I was unsuccessful in any. Could someone help me calculate it and explain the method?*

$$
1) \lim_{h\to 0} =\frac{\frac{\sqrt{(x+h)+1}}{2-(x+h)}-\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{2-x}}h
$$

$$
2)\lim_{z\to x} =\frac{\frac{\sqrt{z+1}}{2-z}-\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{2-x}}{z-x}
$$

$$
3)\;f(x)= \frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{2-x}; u=\sqrt{x+1}
$$
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} =\frac{\frac{u+h}{3-(u+h)^2}-\frac{u}{3-u^2}}h
$$

$$
4)\;f(x)= \frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{2-x}; u={x+1};
$$
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} =\frac{\frac{\sqrt{u+h}}{3-(u+h)}-\frac {\sqrt{u}}{3-u}}h
$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{x+1+h}}{2-x-h}-\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{2-x}&=\frac{\sqrt{x+1+h}-\sqrt{x+1}}{2-x-h}+\frac{h\sqrt{x+1}}{(2-x-h)(2-x)}\\\\
&=\frac{h}{(2-x-h)(\sqrt{x+1+h}+\sqrt{x+1})}+\frac{h\sqrt{x+1}}{(2-x-h)(2-x)}\\\\
\end{align}$$

Now divide by $h$ and let $h\to 0$ to find

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{2-x}\right)=\frac{1}{2(2-x)\sqrt{x+1}}+\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{(2-x)^2}$$

Comment: Very nice indeed!

Comment: @user Much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the contribution! I really liked your solution. Some operations were not very clear to me.

Comment: @Luan You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Please that you enjoyed  this one!

Comment: As far as the operations, in the first line, we just created a common denominator and separated terms.  To move to the second line, just multiply the first term on  the right-hand side of the first line by $1 =\frac{\sqrt{x+1+h}+\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x+1+h}+\sqrt{x+1}}$

Comment: Furthermore , if the other solution is more elegant!

Answer (score 4):

We have that

$$\frac{\frac{\sqrt{(x+h)+1}}{2-(x+h)}-\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{2-x}}h=\frac{\left(\frac{\sqrt{(x+h)+1}}{2-(x+h)}-\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{2-x}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{(x+h)+1}}{2-(x+h)}+\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{2-x}\right)}{h\left(\frac{\sqrt{(x+h)+1}}{2-(x+h)}+\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{2-x}\right)}=$$

$$=\frac{\frac{(x+h)+1}{(2-(x+h))^2}-\frac{x+1}{(2-x)^2}}{h\left(\frac{\sqrt{(x+h)+1}}{2-(x+h)}+\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{2-x}\right)}=\frac{\frac{((x+h)+1)(2-x)^2-(x+1)(2-(x+h))^2}{(2-(x+h))^2(2-x)^2}}{h\left(\frac{\sqrt{(x+h)+1}}{2-(x+h)}+\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{2-x}\right)}=\ldots$$

and since (the cancellation in red is the crucial step)

$$((x+h)+1)(2-x)^2-(x+1)(2-(x+h))^2=$$

$$=\color{red}{(x+1)(2-x)^2}+h(2-x)^2\color{red}{-(x+1)(2-x)^2}+2h(x+1)(2-x)-h^2(x+1)=$$

$$=h(2-x)^2+2h(x+1)(2-x)-h^2(x+1)$$

we obtain

$$\ldots=\frac{\frac{h(2-x)^2+4h(x+1)(2-x)+h^2(x+1)}{(2-(x+h))^2(2-x)^2}}{h\left(\frac{\sqrt{(x+h)+1}}{2-(x+h)}+\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{2-x}\right)}=\frac{(2-x)^2+2(x+1)(2-x)-h(x+1)}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{(x+h)+1}}{2-(x+h)}+\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{2-x}\right)\left((2-(x+h))^2(2-x)^2\right)}\to$$

$$\to \frac{(2-x)^2+2(x+1)(2-x)}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{2-x}+\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{2-x}\right)(2-x)^4}=\frac{(2-x)+2(x+1)}{2\sqrt{x+1}(x-2)^2}=\frac{x+4}{2\sqrt{x+1}(x-2)^2}$$

Comment: On the other hand, this one is not so bad (See my answer) ;-)).

Comment: For what it's worth, the quotient rule can be derived from the chain rule and product rules if you are familiar with those. If not, then I'd highly recommend watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YG15m2VwSjA) video from 3Blue1Brown (he makes maths intuitive):

Comment: @MarkViola Yes of course! Quotient rule is derived from the definition therefore we can obtain that also in this way! But I don't suggest to follow that way in general or in an exam :)

Comment: Thanks for the contribution! This problem really requires a lot of effort and the quotient rule would be more appropriate. But I really needed to prove the derivative by the limit definition.

Comment: @Luan That's fine I didn't get at first you were looking for a specific solution by the definition! The solution given by Mark is very fine to proceed in that way. You are welcome! Bye

Comment: @user I agree that the product rule/quotient rule/chain rule facilitate analysis.  But I thought that the OP wanted to see things developed from direct application of the definition.

Comment: @MarkViola Yes indeed I just realized that. At first it was not clear to me from the formulation for the qustion. I'll delete that!

Comment: Well, the question does state "How would you calculate a derivative by the limit definition with a square root in the numerator?"  So, I took the question literally.

Comment: @MarkViola Yes of course! Now it is completely clear to me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Taking the first definition :
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{\sqrt{(x+h)+1}}{2-(x+h)}-\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{2-x}}h  = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{(x+h)+1}(2-x)-\sqrt{x+1}(2-(x+h))}{(2-(x+h))(2-x)h}$$$$=
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{(x+h+1)(2-x)^2-(x+1)(2-x-h)^2}{(2-x-h)(2-x)h( \sqrt{(x+h)+1}(2-x)+\sqrt{x+1}(2-(x+h)) )} $$

$$= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h^2(-x-1)+h(-x^2-2x+8)}{(2-x-h)(2-x)h( \sqrt{(x+h)+1}(2-x)+\sqrt{x+1}(2-(x+h)) )} $$ $$= \frac{-x^2-2x+8}{(2-x)^2\cdot(2\sqrt{x+1}(2-x))}=-\frac{x+4}{2(2-x)^2\sqrt{x+1}}
$$

Too heavy calculations though, don't use the definition for such derivatives.

Comment: Your solution was also very useful to me! Thank you so much for your contribution. I was very afraid to change the denominator, but I saw that it was a more practical way.

Comment: (+1) for the enormous effort!